# display an error if a date is older than an other date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, alert

I just started to use javascript since few days.

Actually I try do display an error if a date is inferior to an other date, so I've done the following function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function verif_prescription()
{
    var date1= document.getElementById('date1').value;
    var date2= document.getElementById('date3').value;
    if(date1>date2)
    {
        alert('Vous ne pouvez pas avoir une date de prescription inferieure a la date d\'emission');
        document.getElementById('enreg1').setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('enreg1').removeAttribute('disabled')
    }
}
</script>
```

But actualy it does not work for all dates for example if I have on date1= 23-04-2010 and on date3 = 22-04-2012 it display the error, but it should not. SO I think it does not compare the error, I've been looking for something to do like in php but I did not find anything.

Kind regards.
SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/rd13/vnMUZ/

```
  var date1 = "23-04-2012".split('-');
  var date2 = "22-04-2012".split('-');

  var d1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1], date1[0]);
  var d2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1], date2[0]);

  document.write(d1 > d2);
```

or:

```
new Date(Date.parse("08/11/2012","dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Date.parse("24-04-2012"); // Wouldn't work unless you specify the format as being dd/mm/yyy, i.e. UK format.

Comment: dear Sir Thanks for your quick reply, may I do something like document.getElementByID('date1').split('-') ?